# Not getting All FieldValues in Powershell CSOM Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, powershell-script

I have created powershell script to get File/Folder Size details of Sharepoint site.

However, I am not able to get all fieldValues of listItems. I am getting values for $listItem.FieldValues["FileRef"], $listItem.FieldValues["FileRef"] etc. whereas When I am trying  $listItem.FieldValues["File_x0020_Size"] or $listItem.FieldValues["EncodedAbsUrl"], I am getting nothing. In CSOM, We can include required property in .Load, Not sure how to do it in Powershell. Thank You in Advance

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

function retrieveListItems($_web)
{

try
{
    Write-host "Processing Web :"$_web.URL
    $listCollection=$_web.Lists;
    $ctx.Load($listCollection);
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();


    foreach ($list in $listCollection)
    {
        $ctx.Load($list.RootFolder)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $weburl= $ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl
        $listUrl =$("{0}{1}" -f $ctx.Web.Url.Replace($ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl,''), $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)


       if($list.Hidden -ne "true" -and $list.IsCatalog -ne "true" -and  $list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
       {          

            "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $list.Title, $list.BaseType, $list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,$list.Title,"EnterSize", $list.LastItemModifiedDate, $list.ItemCount | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append 
             Write-host $list.Title

            $listItems = $list.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
            $ctx.Load($listItems);
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery();


            foreach($listItem in $listItems)
            {

               # $sizeMB = "{0:N2}" -f (($listitem["File_x0020_Size"])/1MB)  
                 #Here I am getting $sizeMB=0
               $length=$listItem.File.Length
                 #Here I am getting $length=0

               $sizeN=$listItem.FieldValues["File_x0020_Size"]
                #Here I am getting $sizeN=0

               #check if ListItem is Folder or File
                if($listItem["FSObjType"] -eq 1)
                {                    
                    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $listItem["FileLeafRef"],'Folder',$listItem["FileRef"],$list.Title,$sizeMB,$listItem["Modified"],$listItem["ItemChildCount"] | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append
                }
                else
                {
                    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $listItem["FileLeafRef"],'ListItem',$listItem["FileRef"],$list.Title,$sizeMB,$listItem["Modified"],$listItem["ItemChildCount"] | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append
                }
            }   

        }     
    }
    if($_web.Webs.Count -gt 0) 
    {
         foreach($subSite in $_web.Webs)
        { 

           $ctx.Load($subSite)
           $ctx.Load($subSite.Webs)
           $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

         $size = GetWebSize($subSite)  
         $sizeMB = "{0:N2}" -f (($size)/1MB)

           "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $subSite.Title, 'Site', $subSite.ServerRelative,'',$sizeMB, $subSite.LastItemModifiedDate, $subSite.ItemCount | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append 
           retrieveListItems($subSite) 
         }
     }
   $ctx.Dispose()
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
    $_ | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    exit
}

}


function GetWebSize ($web)      
{  
$ctx.Load($web.Folders) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
[long]$total = 0  
foreach ($folder in $web.Folders) {  
    $total += GetFolderSize -Folder $folder  
}          
return $total  
}  

function GetFolderSize ($folder)  
{  
$ctx.Load($folder.Files) 
$ctx.Load($folder.Folders) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery(); 
[long]$folderSize = 0   
foreach ($file in $folder.Files) { 
    $folderSize += $file.Length;  
}  
foreach ($fd in $folder.Folders) {  
    $folderSize += GetFolderSize -Folder $fd  
}  
return $folderSize  
}  


function generateSiteDataReports
{
try
{

    $siteCollectionUrl= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Site Collection URL"

    $Username =  Read-Host -Prompt "Enter userName: ";

    $password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password: " -AsSecureString ;        

    $logFile = "$PSScriptRoot\log.txt"

    if(Test-Path $logFile)
    {
        Remove-Item $logFile
    }

    $outputFile = "$PSScriptRoot\SiteReport.csv"



    # Remove existing output file
    if(Test-Path $outputFile)
    {
         Remove-Item $outputFile
    }


    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f "Title", "Object Type", "URL","ListName","Size", "Modified", "ItemCount" | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append
    $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteCollectionUrl);
    $ctx.Credentials=New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $password);

    $ettkundWeb=$ctx.Web
    $ctx.Load($ettkundWeb)
    $ctx.Load($ettkundWeb.Webs)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get Web Size
   # $size = GetWebSize($ettkundWeb)  
    $sizeMB = "{0:N2}" -f (($size)/1MB)  
   # $sizeGB = "{0:N2}" -f (($size)/1GB) 

    "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $ettkundWeb.Title, 'Site', $ettkundWeb.ServerRelativeUrl,'',"Enter FileSize", $ettkundWeb.LastItemModifiedDate, $subSite.ItemCount | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append 

    Write-host "Processing Web :"   $ettkundWeb.URL
    retrieveListItems($ettkundWeb)

}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
    $_ | Out-File -FilePath $logFile -Append
    exit
}

}

generateSiteDataReports
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
foreach($listItem in $listItems)
         {
             if($listItem.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File")
             {
                 $file = $listItem.File
                 $fileProps = $file.ListItemAllFields
                 $context.Load($file)
                 $context.Load($fileProps)


                 $context.ExecuteQuery()    
                 $sizeN=$fItem["File_x0020_Size"]
                 #Here I am getting $sizeN=0

                 #check if ListItem is Folder or File
                 if($listItem["FSObjType"] -eq 1)
                 {                    
                     "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $listItem["FileLeafRef"],'Folder',$listItem["FileRef"],$list.Title,$sizeMB,$listItem["Modified"],$listItem["ItemChildCount"] | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     "{0}`t{1}`t{2}`t{3}`t{4}`t{5}`t{6}" -f $listItem["FileLeafRef"],'ListItem',$listItem["FileRef"],$list.Title,$sizeMB,$listItem["Modified"],$listItem["ItemChildCount"] | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile -Append
                 }   
             }
         }
```

Refer following link:
https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-document-without-version-in-sharepoint-using-powershell-script-client-side-object-model/

Comment: getting Exception "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" on ExecuteQuery.

Comment: Thank you for Hitendra for link.

Answer (score 0):

I had to replace CAML Query. Now I am able to get All fieldValues. Following code change for reference:

```
$camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$camlQuery.ViewXml ="<View Scope='RecursiveAll' />";
$listItems=$list.GetItems($camlQuery)           
$ctx.Load($listItems);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```